# Can you detect the speed at which an optical disc was burned?

Tags: dvd-burning, disc, cd-burning

If you have some burned discs that don't work, you might want to find out at what speed they were burned to perhaps try and re-burn at a lower speed. So if you don't know the original burning speed, how can you find out?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this information is recorded on the media anywhere. It is prudent to set your burning software to verify the disc after burning and catch speed issues immediately after they occur.

Comment: That doesn't help much, because a DVD writer on a computer may be able to read and verify the burnt disc just fine, but it may not work in a DVD player or a game console. I know this information isn't recorded on the disc, which is why I want to know if there's any method of 'discovering' it later.

Answer (score 0):

If you already "know this information isn't recorded on the disc", then there's no way to find it out later.

Keep in mind that the raw DVD bitstream that is read from the media **always** needs to conform to the specification. This means the bitstream shall always be the same, no matter if burned at 1x speed or (theoretically) 40x.  This is supported by the fact that you can always read a DVD that was burned with a higher speed than the player has.

I guess the best way would be to just write the speed onto the disc with a marker pen.